# How to use where.not with Monologue gem's tagging reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, monologue

I'm using the Monologue gem for blogging on my rails 4.0.4 app. I need to find all the posts that don't have a specific tag. The following attempts at trying to do this are not working:

```
Monologue::Post.includes(:taggings).references(:taggings).where.not(taggings: { tag_id: 1 })
```

I get what looks to be the proper query but about halfway down it shows:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: taggings.tag_id: SELECT "monologue_posts"
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [the table name](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue/blob/master/db/migrate/20120612013442_create_taggings.rb) is `monologue_taggings` not `taggings`.

Try this?

```
Monologue::Post.includes(:taggings)
               .references(:taggings)
               .where.not(monologue_taggings: { tag_id: 1 })
```

Comment: Bingo. Thank you so much. I thought "monologue" was prepended to "taggings" because all the monologue tables are (because it's mounted as an engine) so I thought rails would figure that out :p

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it doesn't.  I've been bitten by the same inconsistency so I feel your pain. :)